# How to use jasmine-require with Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

I would like to use my require.js for Backbone within a Jasmine test suite; and I am working on the setup.

I've seen the use of https://github.com/scottburch/jasmine-require in this test setup: https://github.com/Patternslib/Patterns/blob/master/tests/index.html

Now, I would like to inject Backbone into the game:

```
describe("Basic view test", function() {

  var view;

  requireDependencies(["underscore", "backbone"], function(_, Backbone) {
    view = Backbone.View.extend({el: "li" });
  });

  it("has el property", function() {
    expect(view.el).toBe("li");
  });

});
```

But my Backbone setup is not loaded correctly, see screenshot:

[image: backbone not loading]

What's missing?

My current setup is here: https://github.com/mulderp/backbone-require-test/tree/master/spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the load orders of the dependencies in the global scope that is not seen in the question.
Make sure underscore is loaded before backbone.